# Share Documents with External User using Live ID?

Tags: authentication, document

I get this question from potential customers at every seminar we hold, but I'm unable to answer. Problem is I can’t find the pod cast or other source which described this issue.

**Is it possible to share documents to external users using Live ID?** That would be without placing them in Active Directory. I guess it would be possible if we already have external access via FIM for our internal users – but I’m not sure.

<sup>Environment: **SharePoint 2010**</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would point the customer towards the share functionality in SharePoint Online. But if you want to do this custom then yes it is very possible.

Take a look at [Windows Live ID authentication for SharePoint 2010 on codeplex](http://spwla.codeplex.com/), this would become the basis of what would be a custom page in SharePoint to server the requested file.

Comment: Thanx! This is what I'm after!